# KiCad Eeschema: Defining separate power rails for hierarchical sheets

Tags: kicad

I have a root sheet like the following, and I'm having issues figuring out how to properly define separate power nets for each hierarchical sheet.

As in the image below, I have two circuits separated by a connector.

How can I keep the power nets of these two circuits separate?

[image: Root Sheet]

My current attempt at this was to do the following in the sub sheet, but it doesn't seem to work since my understanding is that the default power nets are global (are connected across sheets).

[image: Sub Sheet]

If this isn't possible, should I be creating a new project for each separate circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You really want to separate power nets the solution is quite simple: just give them different names and **do not** connect them together on any of the projects' sheets.

You've already connected `+5V` and `GND` directly to `Clock Generator` and I assume You also use the same net names on `Clock Generator` sheet. Next, `P38` and `P40` are connected to `Memory Unit` sheet - to this point it's fine, You have separated nets. Now You have to give different names to power nets on `Memory Unit` sheet, for example `+5Vmem` and `GNDmem`.

Comment: Or instead of a power component (like 5V or 12V) simply use a global labels and add a power flag to them.

Comment: How do you rename a power net? When I try to edit the field value of a power component it is greyed out. Should I just use generic net lables?

Comment: Use generic net and add power flag, as @GAttuso suggests or just use another power net from library - there are plenty of them in standard KiCad library.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I think I'm getting on the right track however when I add power flags to different hierarchical sheets ERC complains that power outputs are connected together, even though the nets have different names.